# What will GC do if there is a two level soft referenced object

Tags: java, garbage-collection, soft-references

I know in Java we have concept of soft reference. What if:

1) There is a soft reference "sf" refer to an object A

2) In object A, it has a strong reference refers to object B

3) object A & B are not referenced anywhere else.

By definition, object A and object B are both "softly reachable", right?

Then say we are running out of memory now, GC kicks in. Is it possible that GC will recycle object B but not object A?

If that's the case, later if we want to access object B through "sf", it will be null. How java avoid such case to happen?

I don't see any explain in java doc.

Comment: I would assume that the GC would either collect both A and B or neither of them as it makes logical sense, but this is just speculation.

Answer (score 6):

> Then say we are running out of memory now, GC kicks in. Is it possible that GC will recycle object B but not object A?

No.  The GC will not break strong references in reachable objects.  (It will, of course break references in unreachable objects as part of the reclamation process.  But you can't observe that happening ... because to observe it, you'd need the object to still be reachable.)

This is a consequence of this statement in the javadoc for the `java.lang.ref` package.

*"Finally, an object is unreachable, **and therefore** eligible for reclamation, when it is not reachable in any of the above ways."*

... where "the above ways" includes strong, soft, weak and phantom reachability.

The two highlighted words mean that eligibility for reclamation is a consequence of being in the unreachable state.  Since none of the other states mention reclamation eligibility, we conclude that non-reachability is a precondition for reclamation.

This certainly aligns with common sense.  If (hypothetically) the GC was allowed to "null out" strong references in reachable objects, it would be impossible for an application to safely work with objects after they had gotten into this state.  (Consider the case where the nulled-out reference was in an instance of a library class ...)

Comment: Do you have a source that states this?

Comment: @Jeffrey: it would completely break the language semantics.  Any reference in any part of your program could arbitrary become null at any time for no apparent reason, if any outside piece uses a WeakReference.  It would be terrible!

Comment: @StevenSchlansker It wouldn't affect any reference in any part of my program, only softly or weakly reachable ones.

Comment: @Jeffrey Either the softly reachable object is GCed or it is not. Just imagine all the chaos if you suddenly had objects that were partly GCed, but still reachable. NPEs from things like `if (foo != null) foo.bar();` would be quite confusing wouldn't it?

Comment: @Stephen Added a small addendum about GCing object A. It's obvious, but I think it can't harm to be explicit there. Revert if you don't like it.

Comment: See the [`java.lang.ref` package documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html#reachability) for some background on reachability.

Comment: Regarding "It may GC object A though and as a consequence also object B." This is correct. Java doc says it. But there is not explicit explain about how GC will do to object B. object B is "soft reachable", will GC trace back to object A is a question.

Comment: @Voo While NPE's from `if (foo != null) foo.bar()` are definitely undesirable, this is a constant issue when dealing with multithreaded programs. While I would assume that B would never be collected without collecting A, I don't think the fact that weird NPE's can arise is dispositive.

Comment: @diev There's a *big* difference between a multithreaded program and some internal JVM thread just pulling out the rug under your feet. Also yes I've seen lots of bugs in multithreaded programs that came down to this. No reason to introduce an additional bug farm for no discernable benefit.

Comment: @Voo I assumed that's the way the GC worked, but I haven't seen any Java documentation explicitly saying that's how it worked. That's what I'm after.

Comment: @Jeffrey Well then you can read my post about a short introduction to tracing GCs. That should give you a basic idea :)

Comment: @dlev - those "weird NPEs" are unconnected to the GC.  They are a consequence of the documented non-deterministic behaviour of the memory model if you don't have a "comes before" relationship for a particular usage.

Comment: @StephenC, thanks for your update. Actually you reminds me another question I have. What is "reclamation"? Is it one step in GC? Does it mean that "softly reachable" object is not eligible for "reclamation" but it is eligible for GC?

Comment: @performanceuser - reclamation is another word for the final deletion of an object.  You can figure out the rest for yourself :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think a short introduction on how tracing GCs basically work should clear things up.

A tracing GC (the ones used in Java and .NET all fall into that category) has a set of so called `root pointers`, those are global variables (in java that means static variables of classes) and all live variables in the stackframes. The GC traverses these and marks all objects that are alive, i.e. reachable through references from at least one of the root pointers. When it has finished, all live variables have been marked and the rest can be garbage collected.

A soft reference now can be handled in two different ways: a) we follow the soft reference and mark all objects in it or b) we don't. What exactly happens is at the mercy of the given JVM implementation, but after that has been decided there's no other difference.

Hence there are two possible scenarios:

- The GC follows the soft reference to A in which case none of the two objects will be GCed.
- The GC doesn't follow the soft reference to A (and there are no hard references to it). A is GCed, B is GCed if no live object has a reference to it.

Comment: Thanks that make perfect sense.

Comment: btw, the only true GC roots are the JNI references, the rest of the objects are (should be) eligible for GC (this is why ClassLoader has a `Vector<Class> classes`)

Comment: @bestsss Right you are, but I think leaving all the ugly details out, simplifies the basic understanding. I just hoped nobody'd be asking how Hotspot could unload classes if static variables were really root pointers ;)

Comment: *I think leaving all the ugly details out, simplifies the basic understanding* - totally agree and in the same time I suck at explaining basic stuff

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

"An object is softly reachable if it is not strongly reachable but can be reached by traversing a soft reference."

"An object is strongly reachable if it can be reached by some thread without traversing any reference objects"

I think thats pretty clear. B is softly reachable because it is only reachable by traversing a soft reference.

[Said Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html#reachability)

Comment: I know this. But I want to know the answer of my second more important question.

Comment: Um don't use a SoftReference. Store a reference to B in a strongly referenced cache. A will get collected. Because the graph in traversed downward. Nothing stops you from collecting A because it references B

Comment: I am not trying to get rid of this problem. I am trying to understand how GC works

Comment: GC is all about reachability in your scenario both A and B are eligible for GC because they are by definition softly reachable. If you store a strong reference to B elsewhere it becomes Strongly Reachable but A is still softly reachable and eligible for GC. Keep in mind the java specs only define things in terms of the gaurantees it can make you'll need to reference specific implementations for more specifics on the actual algorithms. Checkout the Glassfish and OpenJDK reference implementations it has lots of great information on how hotspot does things